# Java Application Working fine in Windows 7, Windows XP but not in Windows 2008 Server r2

Tags: java, windows, swing, synchronization, windows-server-2008-r2

I have this Java Swings Application developed by someone else which is delaying the execution on certain processes on Windows Server 2008 r2 32 Bit but it works perfectly in windows XP 32 & Windows 7 32 Bit. 
I have confirmed that the application is running on the same JRE (32 Bit Version) as of the Windows XP & Windows 7.

**Note:
I have tested the application for Delays in Windows XP and Windows 7 and have faced no such issue.
But Windows Server 2008 r2 (32 Bit Operating System) is giving delays in Application logs.**

- Here is the code which is delaying the transaction:

  ```
  private Thread TID;       // The Consumer thread
  private Object q[];       // Queued Values for thread
  private int nQueue;       // Number of items in the Queue
  private int dataStatus;   // Status of the Queue
  private long timeout;

  private String myName;
  private int MaxSize;

  // legal Queue status values
  final static int NONE = 0;     // No data available
  final static int NEW = 1;      // New data available
  final static int OVERRUN = 2;  // Data overrun (queue overflow)
  final static int SHUTDOWN = 3; // Data stream shutdown


  DataItem(Thread t, String name, int Q, long timeo)
  {
      q = new Object[Q];
      nQueue = 0;
      TID = t;
      timeout = timeo;
      dataStatus = NONE;
      myName = name;
      MaxSize = Q;
  }

  DataItem(Thread t, String name, int Q)
  {
      this(t, name, Q, 10);
  }

  /** shorter version for a queue size of two (2) */
  DataItem(Thread t, String name)
  {
      this(t, name, 2, 3000);
  }



   synchronized Object fetch(Trace log) throws DataStreamOverrun,
                                     DataStreamShutdown,
                                     DataStreamTimeout
  {
      Object r = null;

      /* If nothing is waiting, we sleep.*/
      if (dataStatus == NONE)
      {
          log.event("dataStatus :"+dataStatus);
          try
          {
              long was = System.currentTimeMillis();
  //              wait();
              log.event("was :"+was);
              wait(timeout);
              log.event("timeout :"+timeout);
              if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - was) >= timeout)
                  throw new DataStreamTimeout();
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e){
              log.event("SHUTDOWN :"+SHUTDOWN);
              dataStatus = SHUTDOWN; 
          }
      }

      if(nQueue > 0)
      {
          log.event("--------- " + "Version ( " + MyPin.getVersion() +
                  " ) ---------");
          log.event("Reading msg from stream : " + myName +
                  " size(" + nQueue + "/" + MaxSize + ")");
      }
      /* Data (or Status) has arrived so dispatch it. */
      switch (dataStatus)
      {
          case NONE:
              break;
          case NEW:
              r = q[0];
              System.arraycopy(q, 1, q, 0, q.length - 1);
              nQueue--;
              break;
          case OVERRUN:
              dataStatus = NEW; // Next call will get the data
              throw new DataStreamOverrun();
          case SHUTDOWN:
              throw new DataStreamShutdown();
      }
      if (nQueue == 0)
        dataStatus = NONE;
      return r;
  }
  ```

Comment: update the jre with 64 bit

Comment: The Client is using Windows Server 2008 r2 (32 Bit Operating System).

Comment: @RAS: 
The Java Application which is facing transaction delays is coded in Java Swings.
The application involves synchronization coding, which i think is facing Lock on resources or starvation of some thread, and hence timed out is coming.
The code is working just fine for Windows XP and Windows 7, but i cant explain why is it is giving timed out in Windows Server 2008 r2.
Please Help me with this.